# Deciding Runtime Props Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am creating a component in `react.js` using typescript. I am stuck for a while to figure out how i can make one `prop` compulsory either of two. I am creating a `Label` component. It should either receive an `icon` or `title` in props. The way i used to pass props is:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';

export interface LabelProps{
  className?: string;
  onClick?: () => void;
  icon: string,
  title: string
}

export const Label = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, LabelProps>(function(
  { className, onClick, icon, title },
  ref,
) {
  return (
    <div className={clsx(className, 'label')} onClick={onClick} ref={ref}>
      // My Way to display thing's
    </div>
  );
});

export default Label;
```

Now, i know i can check the value of both `icon` and `title` in props and render respectively. But i want typescript to not allow me passing both of them and display an error. I want to use this component as:

```
<Label icon={icon} />
```

or

```
<Label title={title} />
```

But not as the following. Typescript should complain about this:

```
<Label icon={icon} title={title} />
```

Can you show me a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try doing this.
This helps making Props (title, icon) Interdependent, Or No Prop (title, icon) at all.

```
export interface BaseLabelProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLLabelElement> {
  className?: string;
}

interface LabelWithIconProps extends BaseLabelProps {
  icon?: string;
  title?: never;
}

interface LabelWithoutIconProps extends BaseLabelProps {
  icon?: never;
  title?: string;
}

export type LabelProps = LabelWithoutIconProps | LabelWithIconProps;
```